# IIS serving up a blank page when returning a 401

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

When a user does not have any permissions or the right permissions to an action in my application, I return an `HttpUnauthorizedResult`.  When running locally and on our old set of servers, this would show the IIS 401 page to let them know the issue.  However, I recently deployed to a new environment, and I am just getting a blank page.  I've pulled up Fiddler and I can see that I'm getting a 0 content length returned from the server, so it's definitely something on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up Server Manager and go to Roles, then scroll down to **Web Server (IIS)**.  Make sure that Http Errors is Installed under **Role Services**.